# Where is "línea" used in addition to "cola"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario

Someone in Spain corrected me recently when I used the word *línea* instead of *cola*. But today I heard a Spanish speaker doing the same thing, using *línea* to mean line of people. Is this a Latin American thing?

Comment: Normally, in Spain we translate "queue" as "cola".

Comment: A «línea» of people is accepted by the DRAE so it must be normal somewhere, but in the Peninsula I've heard «cola» much more often, followed by «fila» (the latter with a sense of formation more than of waiting turn, e.g. school children).

Comment: I didn't know `línea` could be a valid translation and thought it was a Spanglish word, but after @guillem 's comment I see DRAE indeed accepts it (http://dle.rae.es/?id=NMmmxZf 10th definition)

Comment: In México it's usually "fila". "Cola" has negative connotations in much of Latin America. I've used línea a few times in Mexico, but it seems like an overly literal translation from English.

Comment: Here in Spain, *fila* and *cola* are right in this context. Nobody use *línea* to refer a "queue" of people.

Answer (score 2):

**Hacer cola** o **estar en la cola** dan la idea de estar esperando turno para ser atendidos o para entrar. Se puede aún estar en la cola en un consultorio médico sin estar parados o haciendo fila, estás en una lista de espera, estás en la cola, sentado.

Si la línea no implica esperar turno, se suele decir **hacer fila** o **estar en fila**, como cuando alguien instruye **caminemos en fila india**, o **formen cuatro filas**. No se usaría cola para esto.

**Línea** es más general, sólo describiendo que las personas están una tras otra, pero pierde las ideas de turno o de formación. El uso de **línea** en lugar de **cola** me parece un anglicismo por cierto muy común.

Comment: Just to add that line in this sense is a North American usage, in the UK we say queue, but I agree it is probably an anglicism.